# How to define more values with pattern attribute

Tags: html

I have a input form with pattern attribute. I see that there I can add this for example

```
pattern="2222"
```

And the input field will take only this value, now I want to add more values, for example I want to accept 10 values. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use javascript. Use this code

```
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function checkcode ( form )
{
  var pattern = /name="code" value="|value|value1|value2|"/g
  if (!pattern.test(form.code.value)) {
    alert( "The code is incorrect." );
    form.code.focus();
    return false ;
  }

  return true ;
}

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pattern` attribute can accept a Regular Expression, for example:

```
<input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" />
```

The above `input` will accept only 3 alphabetical (regardless of case) charaacters. If you only want to allow 4-digit numbers, use:

```
<input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[0-9]{4}" />
```

Comment: You don't understand me, for example I want to accept only this values in input form: 2222, 3333, 4444 each number is a value

Comment: Yes, I do understand you. Do you know what regular Expressions are? You can easily achieve that with those. I've updated the answer for your reference.

Comment: What about a javascript that validate this input field with only words/values I declare

Comment: **Read up on Regular Expressions**. They can achieve what you're looking for; that's why the `pattern` attribute accepts them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a select, or regular expressions matching whatever you want to match.